# Исправьте ошибку в цикле в коде в Python

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая находит кота.

Пользователь вводит строки до тех пор, пока он не введёт «СТОП». Программа выводит, во-первых, общее количество строк, в которых были упомянуты коты, во-вторых, номер строки, на которой впервые был упомянут кот (в том же смысле, что и в предыдущих задачах), или -1 (минус один), если кот не был упомянут.

```
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
while True:
   a = input().lower()
   b += 1
   if 'стоп' in a:
       break
   elif 'кот' in a:
       d += 1
       c = b
       break
       print(d, c)
   elif 'кот' not in a:
       d = 0
       c = -1
print(d, c)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните заголовок вопроса [ask]

Comment: @dIm0n уточнил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

почему нельзя переменные хоть как-то по человечески называть? :) И много лишнего функционала в коде

```
line_index = 0
lines_count = 0
first_line = -1

while True:
    text = input().lower()

    line_index += 1

    if 'стоп' in text:
        break
   
    if'кот' in text:
        lines_count += 1
        first_line = line_index if first_line == -1 else first_line

print(lines_count, first_line)
```

у вас же в коде если не находится кот в строке

```
elif 'кот' not in a:
    d = 0
    c = -1
```

зачем то в 0 сбрасывается кол-во строк с котом и номер строки в -1 - в результате по сути сколько бы котов не было -  учитываются только последовательно идущие строки с котами, заканчивающиеся командой "стоп"